# Finding whether current time is between a range provided in string (hh:mm) like 10:30-11:30 or 12:30-13:30 etc

Tags: objective-c, datetime, string-parsing

I want to check whether the whether current time is between a range provided in string.

for example: range = 10:30 - 15:45 and current time is 11:50, in this case method should return YES else NO(for 15:50).

I am using following code, that is working fine. But i am looking for some optimized ways. can any one suggest me , What other good way can achieve the same.

```
-(BOOL)checkTimeRange :(NSString *)timeRange
{
    NSUInteger lowerRange = [[timeRange substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] integerValue] * 60* 60 + [[timeRange substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 2)] integerValue] * 60;

    NSUInteger upperRange = [[timeRange substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)] integerValue] * 60 * 60 + [[timeRange substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(9, 2)] integerValue] * 60;

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSUInteger currentTime = hour *60*60 + minute*60;

    if(currentTime >= lowerRange && currentTime <= upperRange)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Optimised for what? Number of lines of code? Speed? Done any profiling? If it works, why do you want to change it?

Comment: I want to make it short, so optimize for Number of lines of code

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Review, belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can actually remove the change lines and make everything into 1 line. But this won't improve the performance, but make readability worse.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code is not safe in `lowerRange` and `upperRange` initializing parts. What if your string contains wrong data? In this case your program will crash. You need to check the argument. Use the `NSRegularExpression` for this and more. You can get the ranges with it. Take a look at the [reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html) for more patterns.

```
- (BOOL)checkTimeRange:(NSString *)timeRange
{
  if(!timeRange || timeRange.count==0)
    return NO;
  NSError *error;
  NSRegularExpression *regexpr = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(0-9|:)" options:0 error:&error];
  if (error)
     return NO;
  NSArray *matches = [regexpr matchesInString:timeRange options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,timeRange.length)];
  if (!matches || matches.count<2)
    return NO;
  NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
  // get the dates
  NSDate *date0 = [formatter dateFromString:matches[0]];
  NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:matches[1]];
  // get components from the dates...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two NSDate objects from your time interval, one for start time & other for end time.

Get 3rd NSDate from your current time.

```
[date1 compare:date2]==NSOrderDescending means date2 is smaller than date1 and so..
```

Hope this helps..